# why do we need setTimeout to close the connection in rabbitMQ with javascript

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using rabbitMQ with javascript. With all the examples provided by rabbitMQ are closing the connection using setTimeout of around 500ms. When I tried colsing connection with any delay then the things didn't workout.

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var ex = 'logs';
    var msg = process.argv.slice(2).join(' ') || 'Hello World!';

    ch.assertExchange(ex, 'fanout', {durable: false});
    ch.publish(ex, '', new Buffer(msg));
    console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
  });
```

> setTimeout(function() { conn.close(); process.exit(0) }, 500);

```
});
```

Answer (score 0):

nearly all of the operations w/ amqplib and rabbitmq are asynchronous. if you exit the app immediately, there is no guarantee that the operations have completed.

you can mitigate the need for `setTimeout` by using the callback function everywhere it is supported, including the `assertExchange` call you are making:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var ex = 'logs';
    var msg = process.argv.slice(2).join(' ') || 'Hello World!';

    ch.assertExchange(ex, 'fanout', {durable: false}, function(){
      ch.publish(ex, '', new Buffer(msg));
      console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);

      conn.close(); 
      process.exit(0);
    });

  });
});
```

where you place the `process.exit()` call is important.

by putting it inside of the last callback, you have a better chance of not needing a set timeout. however, [the `publish` method of amqplib](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_publish) does not support callbacks. if there is a delay in publishing the message, exiting immediately may still cause the message to not be sent.